# Android Wear BoxInsetLayout isRound always returns false

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm building an Android Wear app and trying to implement BoxInsetLayout for round screens.  In my code, I want to detect if the device is round or not, so I'm using BoxInsetLayout's isRound() function, but it always returns false, even on the Moto 360.

Anyone know if there's a way to programmatically tell if the device is round?

Comment: Do you use `layout_box` attribute?

Comment: Yes, but what bearing does that have on the return value of isRound()?

Comment: Can you copy paste your manifest?

Comment: Same issue here. Was this ever resolved?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  The boxinsetlayout seems to do it's job correctly, it just insists that the screen is actually square when you use the isRound() function.

I logged a bug for it here:  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76097&q=boxinsetlayout%20isRound%20wear&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Feel free to star it, to maybe get some attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be caused by calling isRound() at the wrong time. The round-ness is determined by the WindowInsets being delivered to the BoxInsetLayout. If you call isRound() very early before the insets have been delivered, you will get the wrong answer.

So if you have a "box" object which is the BoxInsetLayout, you would do this:

```
box.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
        @Override
        public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsets windowInsets) {
            // Need to also call the original insets since we have overridden the original                                                  
            // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener.html                                   
            box.onApplyWindowInsets(windowInsets);

            // You can make calls to detect isRound() here!


            // Return the insets so the BoxInsetLayout still works properly
            return windowInsets;
        }
    });
```

Can you please send us the code related to the BoxInsetLayout that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

According to **Wayne** answer on G+ it is a bug, for now we know what causes it, how to avoid it but only if user is aware of that, but fix for it is not released (yet).

https://plus.google.com/108847189842978537754/posts/5YiYb14i7ss

Quoting as post might be deleted/changed:

> The problem is triggered by the watch switching languages when pairing with a phone after a factory reset. You can avoid the issue by
> selecting the same language on the wearable as you are using on the
> phone, so that no change occurs afterwards when the devices are
> paired.
>
> Instructions to fix the problem:
>
> 1. Factory reset the Moto 360.
> 2. When the wearable restarts, it will ask what language you would like to use. Select the same language that you are using on the phone
>    (do not select the default of English)
> 3. On the phone, start the Android Wear companion app, and select from the overflow menu the option "Pair with a new wearable".
> 4. Pair the phone with the Moto 360.

EDIT:
Using setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener (suggested by Wayne) I created small class that simplify using it a bit. https://github.com/tajchert/ShapeWear

Just copy ShapeWear.java class, and subscribe to screen shape detection event `setOnShapeChangeListener()` or call method `ShapeWear.isRound()` (can throw error is shape is not yet determined) or `ShapeWear. getShape()` - which can result in `ShapeWear.SHAPE_UNSURE` in same situation.